# How do I fix my ssh connection in Debian?

Tags: ssh, debian-jessie

I am trying to run a Minecraft server off of an old laptop I have lying around. I installed Debian "Jessie" and started to go about compiling Bukkit server from git. The problem is my ssh connection disconnects randomly, sometimes when I'm in the middle of inputting a command or a series of commands. Clearly, the session is still active. I made sure ConnectTimeout was set to 0. I have tried changing my ServerAliveInterval, and I can't figure it out.

The problem is further compounded by the fact that after being disconnected, I cannot reconnect.

I don't even know where to start looking for the log files...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I may have fixed my issue with a really simple fix. If anyone else is running into this problem, this may help:

Comment: It is worth noting that I was trying to connect over WiFi with my ssh_config set to listen on all ports. 

It seems the reason for things not working is because there was a conflict with ssh listening on both eth0 and wlan0, You see, I did the dumb thing of configuring them both with the same address. (I needed ethernet only as long as it took to install firmware-realtek)

The fix was simple: I simply needed to disable eth0. I suppose the alternate fix would have been to change the ip of eth0 or to set ssh to listen only on wlan0.

Comment: please, add the answer to the answer field bellow. Comments are for clarification of the question.

Comment: I have experience with mine craft servers, and the idea that you would want to run it over wifi boggles my mind.  How many people will be connected to this server at any one time?  If it is any more than 2-3, I would go wired and probably go get a better machine to run things, but that's just my opinion.